# I have added this below libraries its showing error in this library - compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' why?

Tags: android, firebase, crash, libraries

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
```

> > 
>
> ```
> its showing this error
>
> > All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).
> ```
>
> Found versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0

Comment: you have to use same version for all your android support library

Answer (score 1):

Use everything as unique one:

For eg:

Here I am using 24 version.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 24
    // useJack = true

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    multiDexEnabled true
}

Use all library as same versions. Please check the libraries are same versions.

  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
```

Comment: The error is solved after adding this dependency -     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' but now there are no errors and app is running perfectly through my computer but its crashing if I share the apk and runs it. can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
```

you have a dependencies with the support libraries 24.0.0.

Then you have to change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

with

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
```

Comment: The error is solved after adding this dependency -     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' but now there are no errors and app is running perfectly through my computer but its crashing if I share the apk and runs it. can you tell me why?

Comment: @SanjayVK You should check the stacktrace. Without it is quite impossbile to understand the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the compileSdk version to 23 to remove the error.

Actually the compile sdk version should match the dependencies ie if your compile version is 24 then the dependency should also be 24.

Comment: The error is solved after adding this dependency -     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0' but now there are no errors and app is running perfectly through my computer but its crashing if I share the apk and runs it. can you tell me why?

Comment: It might be because your minSDKVersion is very high or due to some libraries you have used. Can you give the detail of error?

Comment: now there is no error and I can run it properly while connected to my laptop but its crashing while I share the apk and run it

Comment: Yes it might me due to the different version of android. What is the version of your android phone?

Comment: but it works when the same phone is connected to laptop

Comment: then there might be error in sharing the app. Try building apk and after the apk is ready try sharing it